# How does Detect Magic spell see a Warlock's use of Devil's Sight invocation?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, eldritch-invocations

I assume Eldritch Invocations are detected as magic, because they are magic:

> In your study of occult lore, you have unearthed eldritch invocations, fragments of forbidden knowledge that imbue you with an abiding **magical** ability.

And *Detect Magic* spell detects magic like this:

> For the duration, you sense the presence of magic within 30 feet of you. If you sense magic in this way, you can use your action to see a faint aura around any **visible creature** or object in the area **that bears magic**, and you learn its school of magic, if any.

**What does *Detect Magic* reveal about a visible warlock with Devil's Sight?**

I guess there are  two cases: the warlock actually "seeing normally in darkness" with the invocation benefit active, and the warlock being in bright light and invocation not doing anything. Let's leave the murky details of Devil's sight interaction with dim light and the warlock having or not having darkvision out of scope.

Comment: Related: [Can the Detect Magic spell detect prepared spells or spellcasters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49706)

Answer (score 5):

### All warlock invocations are magical

*Devil’s Sight* is ‘always on’. Therefore the warlock is always under a magical effect and this is revealed by *Detect Magic*.